# What are the currently known exactly solvable ODEs?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, big-list

I'm mostly interested in two dimensional systems
$$\dot{x}=f(x,y), \\ \dot{y}=g(x,y), $$
which include the second order ODEs 
$$\ddot{x}=F(t,x,\dot{x}). $$
Putting the linear equations aside, on which we have a comprehensive literature, what are (some of) the nonlinear ODEs for which we have a formula for the general solution, and preferably some understanding of its behaviour? An example is the Weierstraß differential equation
$$\ddot{x}=6x^2-\frac{1}{2}g_2 $$
for which the solution is given by 
$$x(t)=\wp \left(t-t_0;g_2,g_3\right) $$
where $t_0$ and $g_3$ are the integration constants, and $\wp$ is the Weierstraß elliptic function.

Thanks!

**EDIT:**
I'm interested in as many examples as possible, but partial answers are also greatly appreciated.

Comment: I see you have a tag "big-list". This say all...

Comment: @user13377: Since your question is "what are the nonlinear ODEs for which we have a formula for the general solution?", I suppose that you expect us to write a whole handbook on the subject.

Comment: @JeanMarie I meant to get as many as I can, which is why I put the "all" part in parenthesis. Nevertheless, I appreciate any amount given to me, and will edit to reflect that.

Comment: @JJacquelin A reference (if one exists) would be ideal. But yeah, I'm interested in as many examples as possible.

Comment: Could you please clarify what you intend by "...have a formula for the general solution"? If you accept the non-elementary function $\wp$, you have to draw a line somewhere, or else _all_ ODEs risk being "exactly solvable" by their own solution.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang I mean that they can be solved using some special functions that are known in the literature.

Comment: Aren't [Polyanin-Zaytsev](https://books.google.ru/books?id=eB7NBQAAQBAJ&pg=PR21&dq=Polyanin+Zaitsev&hl=ru&sa=X&redir_esc=y) or Kamke books on this topic?

Comment: @Evgeny Thank you very much. I was expecting to see the Jacobian elliptic functions in Polyanin-Zaytsev but I couldn't find it. I will also look in the second book.